# AWS - OS Error permission denied Lambda Script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to execute a Lambda Script in Python with an imported library, however I'm getting permission errors.
I am also getting some alerts about the database, but database queries are called after the subprocess so I don't think they are related. Could someone explain why do I get error?

Alert information

```
Alarm:Database-WriteCapacityUnitsLimit-BasicAlarm 
State changed to INSUFFICIENT_DATA at 2016/08/16. Reason: Unchecked: Initial alarm creation
```

Lambda Error

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: OSError Traceback (most recent call last):File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 36, in lambda_handler     
xml_output = subprocess.check_output(["./mediainfo", "--full", "--output=XML", signed_url]) 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__ errread, errwrite) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child raise child_exception 
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Lambda code

```
import logging
import subprocess

import boto3

SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION = 300     # The number of seconds that the Signed URL is valid
DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME = "TechnicalMetadata"
DYNAMO = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
TABLE = DYNAMO.Table(DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME)

logger = logging.getLogger('boto3')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """

    :param event:
    :param context:
    """
    # Loop through records provided by S3 Event trigger
    for s3_record in event['Records']:
        logger.info("Working on new s3_record...")
        # Extract the Key and Bucket names for the asset uploaded to S3
        key = s3_record['s3']['object']['key']
        bucket = s3_record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        logger.info("Bucket: {} \t Key: {}".format(bucket, key))
        # Generate a signed URL for the uploaded asset
        signed_url = get_signed_url(SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION, bucket, key)
        logger.info("Signed URL: {}".format(signed_url))
        # Launch MediaInfo
        # Pass the signed URL of the uploaded asset to MediaInfo as an input
        # MediaInfo will extract the technical metadata from the asset
        # The extracted metadata will be outputted in XML format and
        # stored in the variable xml_output
        xml_output = subprocess.check_output(["./mediainfo", "--full", "--output=XML", signed_url])
        logger.info("Output: {}".format(xml_output))
        save_record(key, xml_output)

def save_record(key, xml_output):
    """
    Save record to DynamoDB

    :param key:         S3 Key Name
    :param xml_output:  Technical Metadata in XML Format
    :return:
    """
    logger.info("Saving record to DynamoDB...")
    TABLE.put_item(
       Item={
            'keyName': key,
            'technicalMetadata': xml_output
        }
    )
    logger.info("Saved record to DynamoDB")


def get_signed_url(expires_in, bucket, obj):
    """
    Generate a signed URL
    :param expires_in:  URL Expiration time in seconds
    :param bucket:
    :param obj:         S3 Key name
    :return:            Signed URL
    """
    s3_cli = boto3.client("s3")
    presigned_url = s3_cli.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': obj},
                                                  ExpiresIn=expires_in)
    return presigned_url
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to execute a subprocess in your lambda function. You need to show your code if you want help with that. Also, I don't see how the database (DynamoDB?) alert could be related.

Comment: @MarkB I am, what permissions would I need to execute a subprocess on AWS?

Comment: So you have packaged up this "mediainfo" script or executable as part of your Lambda deployment?

Comment: Yes, on a zip file.Else I would get a: File Not Found Err

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that this is a restriction imposed by the lambda execution environment, but it can be worked around by executing the script through the shell.
Try providing shell=True to your subprocess call:

```
xml_output = subprocess.check_output(["./mediainfo", "--full", "--output=XML", signed_url], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I came with this solution the other day but did not tried it. My problem was solved fairly easy, I didn't compress the command as an executable and thus was unable to access it. Making it an exe and compressing again solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation. I was receiving the error:

```
2016-11-28T01:49:01.304Z    d4505c71-b50c-11e6-b0a1-65eecf2623cd    Error: Command failed: /var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl --dump-json -f best https://soundcloud.com/bla/blabla
python: can't open file '/var/task/node_modules/youtube-dl/bin/youtube-dl': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

For my (and every other) Node Lambda project containing third party libraries, there will be a directory called "node_modules" (most tutorials, [such as this one](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/), will detail how this directory is created) that has all the third party packages and their dependencies.  The same principles apply to the other supported languages (currently Python and Java).  **THESE ARE THE FILES THAT AMAZON IS ACTUALLY PUTTING ON THE LAMBDA AMIS AND ATTEMPTING TO USE**.  So, to fix the issue, run this on the node_modules directory (or whatever directory your third party libraries live in):

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/bla/bla/bla/lambdaproject/node_modules
```

This command means making the file readable, writable and executable by all users. Which is apparently what the servers that execute Lambda functions need, in order to work. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: i'm getting the same error even after chmod'ing my node_modules dir. did you have to do anything else? all other modules i've tried seem to work

Comment: Not that I can think of.  My high-level advice is to automate deployment per [something like this](https://medium.com/@AdamRNeary/a-gulp-workflow-for-amazon-lambda-61c2afd723b6#.aggupxrrr) to make sure you don't miss any steps.  For reference, [here's an example](https://github.com/josephecombs/automated_soundcloud_downloading/blob/master/downloadThenUpload/gulpfile.js) of one of my deployment scripts.